# If reference cell contains "x", return "y", otherwise return "z"

Tags: numbers

I'm trying to build what seems like a dang simple formula, but for some reason it's stumping me. Here's the idea:

```
IF(//B4 contains "apple"//),"$100","$200")
```

so that it returns "$100" if B4 contains "apple", or "$200" if it doesn't.

I can't figure out the function to use in the //B4 contains "apple"// part. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
IF(LOOKUP("apple",B4),"$100","$200")
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "apple" is part of the string in B4 cell you can use something like:

`IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("apple";B4));100;200)`

NOTE1: My Numbers uses `;` as a delimiter, you might be using `,` instead.

NOTE2: return integer value and format the cell to show the currency.

Comment: Ahh, this makes more sense -- ISERROR will give me the True or False return I need for the IF statement.

Comment: This brings up another problem though – the cell no longer maintains the Currency format I set it to. In fact, I can't change its format at all. Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: @etudes I tried this and it works for me, however I noticed that Mateusz has also written his suggestion with ; instead of , as delimiter, does it help if you change that?

Comment: @etudes The currency might work better if you return 100 and 200 as numbers, instead of the "$100" and "$200" that are in the expression now.

Comment: @Lizzan (Sorry, I did make it work in the end, thanks.) I tried removing the $ to return just numbers, but it still is not letting me change the format of the cell when there is a function in it.

Comment: @etudes see the edit. I'm able to return integer and format the cell to show currency and it works for me. Also You may want to use `,` as a delimiter.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Thanks, I see it. I did change to `,` for my delimiters. Also changed to return integers, but I still can't format the cell to show currency. Hmm...

Comment: Notice that there is no `”` around integers

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek YOU GENIUS. Got it, thank you. Getting rid of the quotes solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your LOOKUP function to EXACT, so that your formula would read

```
IF(EXACT("apple",B4),"$100","$200")
```

or

```
IF(B4="apple", 100, 200)
```

for a case insensitive solution, or

```
IF(TRIM(B4)="apple",100,200)
```

for a solution which will work even when there's whitespace around the word in the cell (leading/trailing spaces, etc.).

---

My Numbers is set to use ; instead of , as delimiters, so my test sample reads `IF(EXACT("Apple";B4); 100; 200)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This doesn't quite solve the problem though, as I'm trying to see if text is in a part of the cell I'm referring to, while EXACT needs it to match the cell exactly for it to return True.

Comment: @etudes Ah, I missed that part, sorry. Leaving this here in case EXACT works for someone else with a similar question.

Comment: IF(B4="apple",100,200) will also work for a match, case independant though.

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike, I edited that in. I tried a similar version first, but must have discarded it when it didn't work due to not having realised my version wanted ; instead of ,.

Comment: IF(TRIM(B4)="apple",100,200) - trim can also help if people can't type...

Comment: Hi Lizzan, sorry - i was adding options but not on the grounds of requiring you to have to edit your answer - yours made me think as well , cheers